# Migration from TFS 2010 to TFS 2012

Tags: tfs, hardware, tfs-migration

I have been searching the web for a clean solution on how to migrate our 2010 tfs collections to our new tfs 2012 server, but no luck. May someone please assist with the steps or a good blog I could look at to achieve this process. The reason we want to do a MIGRATION and not an upgrade is because we got new hardware and would first like to trial TFS 2012 before we upgrade our live environment. Therefore we would like to import all our collection including  the work items and build process templates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can move a collection at a time using the detach option in 2010 and attach it back to 2012 using the attach option there.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd936138(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Detach and attach is a great way to move a collection across servers.  That said, if you want to upgrade your whole instance (even across hardware) I highly recommend that you do a "true" upgrade.  I've described how to do that in my answer.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a decent blog post: http://mohamedradwan.wordpress.com/2013/01/05/upgrade-tfs-2010-to-tfs-2012-with-migration-to-a-new-hardware-series/

The basic steps you want to follow are:

1. Backup *all* of your 2010 databases.
2. Restore those databases on the SQL Server on your new hardware.
3. On your new hardware, install TFS 2012
4. When it comes time to configure.  Select the upgrade option.
5. It will asks where your databases are.  Select the SQL Server that you used in #2.
6. Press Go.

Note, if you want to test 2012 with the same clients you are using for 2010 then you'll need to "clone" the system otherwise your clients will get confused.  To do that, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee349259.aspx

Comment: What about this scenario:

Comment: My current TFS 2010 implementation of both Application and Data tiers are installed on the same server - a Windows Server 2008 R2 Ent. (with SQL Server 2008 R2). We now wish to upgrade to TFS 2013 and have two new servers we wish to use for the application and data tiers respectively. On the data tier server, we'll also have SQL Server 2012 SP1, as TFS 2013 only supports that version of SQL or later. We therefore have to upgrade SQL from 2008 R2 to 2012 SP1. What's the best way to achieve this? Is it the case that the new server will have to have SQL Server 2008 R2 installed initially?