# migrate TFS 2010 project collection to TFS 2012

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, tfs-migration

Hi can anyone tell me how to migrate existing tfs 2010 project collection to tfs 2012.
my old configuration are given below
TFS 2010, sql server 2008 r2, sharepoint 2010(on separate server)

Now I have configured new servers with following specs
TFS 2012, 
sharepoint 2013
SQL server 2008R2

I want to migrate/attach existing tfs2010 project collection to new tfs 2012 server, if existing sharepoint sites can also be migrated to new sharepoint server then it will be great.

any ideas and help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You will need to use advanced upgrade option, please consult following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14997172/migration-from-tfs-2010-to-tfs-2012, specificly - http://mohamedradwan.wordpress.com/2013/01/05/upgrade-tfs-2010-to-tfs-2012-with-migration-to-a-new-hardware-series/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is:

1. have the old collection (after back up) on the sql server.
2. TFS 2012 installed and configured to the sql server
3. press attach ( migration process start automatically). process takes about 1 hour and 10 minutes.

I know I've done this from 2008->2010->2012 you can check:
[migrate data from TFS 2008 to an already working TFS 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20972422/migrate-data-from-tfs-2008-to-an-already-working-tfs-2012/21383539#21383539)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd936138.aspx. Basically it is about backing your db up and restoring it. Plus some actions for sharepoint sites.